# ldap/AD proxy: Unable to bind using sAMAccountName, but last name and first name is able to bind

Tags: active-directory, debian, proxy, ldap, passthrough

I am attempting to set up a pass-through proxy to Active Directory, using ldap on Debian Wheezy. The slapd.conf file is below. I can bind just find by using lastname, first name:

```
ldapsearch -x -h localhost -b "OU=Site-Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local" -D "cn=LaCroix\, Jay,OU=My Group,OU=Site-Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local" -W "(sAMAccountName=jlacroix)" cn sAMAccountName
```

And that does work:

```
result: 0 Success
```

But what we really want to do is bind via the user name (sAMAccountName):

```
ldapsearch -x -h localhost -b "OU=Site-Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local" -D "cn=jlacroix,OU=My Group,OU=Site-Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local" -W "(sAMAccountName=jlacroix)" cn sAMAccountName
```

and that does not work:

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

Note: Despite that error, my credentials ARE correct, as seen in the first example where binding works via Last Name, First Name.

I have been searching through examples for a number of weeks now, and no matter what I try, I can't seem to bind against sAMAccountName, only Last Name, First Name.

I can search for sAMAccountName when searching against AD directly, but not when using my ldap proxy.

Here is my /etc/ldap/slapd.conf:

```
# Import our schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/samaccountname.schema

moduleload      back_ldap
moduleload      back_bdb.la
moduleload      rwm 

# Support both LDAPv2 and LDAPv3
allow           bind_v2

pidfile         /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
argsfile        /var/run/slapd/slapd.args

loglevel        1   

# Our slapd-ldap back end to connect to AD

database        ldap
suffix          ou=Site-Users,dc=mycompany,dc=local
subordinate
rebind-as-user  yes 
uri             ldap://10.10.10.99:389
chase-referrals yes 
readonly        yes 
#protocol-version       3   

overlay         rwm 
rwm-map         attribute       uid     sAMAccountName
rwm-map         attribute       mail    proxyAddresses 

binddn cn=ADreader 
bindpw supersecretpassword

# Our primary back end 

database        bdb 
suffix          dc=mycompany,dc=local
rootdn          cn=admin,dc=mycompany,dc=local
rootpw          supersecretpassword 
directory       /var/lib/ldap

# Indexes for this back end 
index           objectClass                     eq,pres
index           ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname    eq,pres,sub
index           uid                             eq,pres,sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You're "it works" example works because the DN of the object is `cn=LaCroix\, Jay,OU=My Group,OU=Site-Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local`. The second doesn't work because the DN of the object isn't `cn=jlacroix,OU=My Group,OU=Site-Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local`.

It's not that you're binding with the "Last Name, First Name", rather the CN of the object is set to " Last Name, First Name" and you're binding with the object's CN. You can't just put the `sAMAccountName` in as the CN and expect it to work. The object's CN is the object's CN.

Binding directly to AD with a bind DN of "DOMAIN\sAMAccountName" will work fine. I don't think OpenLDAP will handle that, thought. It's probably going to reject that syntax even though, from Active Directory's perspective, it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, it's starting to make more sense. My goal is to get it to recognize sAMAccountName so that we can utilize it via ldap as a proxy to AD. The tutorial I followed is this one:

http://windowsitpro.com/networking/integrate-active-directory-and-openldap

My understanding (which may be wrong) is that it's supposed to pass the request to AD as a proxy. But that's not what it's doing.

Using just DOMAIN\sAMAccountName doesn't work either, unfortunately.

Thanks!

Comment: For some wicked fun I just set this up on a test box. OpenLDAP's enforcement of the DN syntax for the bind DN is definitely what's causing the "DOMAIN\sAMAccountName" syntax not to work for you. That's a shame, because it probably would work if OpenLDAP would just pass the string through unmodified.